# Multiple definition error ld

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets

I have class. This class I with wxWidgets  macroses make to list. It's working. 
for ex.:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A();
//any function
public:
//any variables 
};

WX_DECLARE_USER_EXPORTED_LIST(A, AList, A_API);
```

but I Use this class in different .cpp files. 
I have error " multiple definition of ..." and "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"
I can not use "inline" function.
Any idea...

Comment: Is this class defined in a header file? Does it have the include guards?

Comment: Multiple definition of what?

Comment: good question. Sorry! I use set_precompiled_header, and all ".h" file exist. My Problem in ld. All "*.o" files is created, but not work linker

Answer (score 0):

Your question is terribly unclear as it doesn't give the errors themselves but it actually doesn't matter because the answer is not to use the old macro-based container list classes any more. Just use `std::list<>` or, better, `std::vector<>`. There is really no reason to use the 1990s approach nowadays.